# Application unfortunately gets stopped

Tags: android

**i am trying to send sms on mobile number but it shows it gets unfortunately stopped**

```
The Full Lgcat Errors: 
    04-05 06:31:19.682: E/AndroidRuntime(2231): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 06:31:19.682:
 E/AndroidRuntime(2231): java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10042 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
04-05 06:31:19.682:
 E/AndroidRuntime(2231):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:434)
04-05 06:31:19.682:
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:79)
04-05 06:31:19.682:
 E/AndroidRuntime(2231):    at com.example.validation.sms$1.onClick(sms.java:43)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
04-05 06:31:19.682:
```

E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 06:31:19.682:
 E/AndroidRuntime(2231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-05 06:31:19.682:
 E/AndroidRuntime(2231):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 06:31:19.682:
 E/AndroidRuntime(2231):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 06:31:19.682:
 E/AndroidRuntime(2231):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-05 06:31:19.682: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2231):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
package com.example.validation;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class sms extends Activity {

EditText e1,e2;
Button b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sms);

e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_no);
e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String no=e1.getText().toString();
String msg=e2.getText().toString();

Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),sms.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity 
(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(no, null, msg, pi, null);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent",      
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
}}
```

Comment: could you post the full logcat so that we understand it better??

Comment: indicate `sms.java:43`

Comment: Please highlight line/no. on which you are getting error..

Comment: Why your class name is in small case??? and change `getApplicationContext(). to sms.this`

Comment: Add this permission to your manifest.xml 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

Comment: @Aks on this lune "SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();".. m getting error

Comment: @usman: thanks its done but can u tell me  how to.sens sms using internet without cost mobile balance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these permissions on your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: thanks gooner.. but can u tell me how to sms using internet because the application i built now it costs money so.. plz

Comment: Accept and close the answer.For simulating sending SMS use android emulator for simulating SMS sending and receiving!

Comment: actu i didn't get. u. nd   wat should I do to send sms on mobile number using internet.....(nd sorry to didn't u. i m totally beginner to Android)..

Comment: The only way to accomplish this is to use an online SMS gateway, which means you send the message to the service provider via the internet, and they forward it to the recipient over SMS. There are several service providers for this, but mostly they require a subscription, i.e. they're not free. Just google to find them.
Some service providers have Android app support, but this depends on your region and the selected service provider.
Note that most service providers don't allow you to use your own number as the sender, therefore the recipient may have a hard time replying to you.

Comment: okay dear.. it seems hard process for me....  as beginner